# Node.js passport-saml redirects to localhost:3000/login/callback all the time

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml, saml-2.0

I am using the tutorial from **www.npmjs.org/package/passport-saml** for the SAML. I am a beginner in SAML.

The tutorial says

> The SAML identity provider will redirect you to the URL provided by the **path** configuration

I already have a OpenIdp account. It seems I can successfully login but the redirect URL always sends me to **localhost:3000/login/callback** which is not present in my code because I changed the **'path'** to **'/users/login-user-db-saml'** or **'www.passporttoken.com:1234/users/login-user-db-saml'** (both doesn't work and still sends me to the default **login/callback**).

I have the code below. What I am doing wrong?

```
/**start FOR SAML**/
passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
    {
        path: '/users/login-user-db-saml',
        entryPoint: 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
        issuer: 'passport-saml'
    },
    function(profile, done) {
        findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    })
);

app.post('/users/login-user-db-sam',
    passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/users/login-user-saml', failureFlash: true }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);

app.get('/users/login-user-saml',
    passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/users/login-user-saml', failureFlash: true }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
/**End for SAML**/
```

Comment: did you initialize passport.session?

Comment: I have the same issue : [similar question][1]

Any ideas how to solve it? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985023/redirect-localhost-instead-of-myserver-org3000-login-callback

Answer (score 3):

I removed the 'path' from the SAML configuration, and instead use a 'callbackUrl' with the full path to the callback specified. I also set 'issuer' as shown below:

```
    saml : {
      entryPoint : 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
      issuer : 'http://192.168.56.101:3000',
      callbackUrl : 'http://192.168.56.101:3000/login/callback' 
    }
```

You should also configure your SAML SP at OpenIdP on the metadata configuration page: https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/metaedit/edit.php - set the AssertionConsumerServiceURL on the SAML 2.0 tab to be your callbackUrl, and set the entityID to be the 'issuer' above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making your SAML Login route a POST request?

SAML wants it to be POST

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in your strategy configuration; especially issuer. Your configuration point to the entity 'passport-saml', which is configured as is. Define your own entity and create settings you need.